# Why is this edited JWT signature validated?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I am using server certificate signed JWTs to secure a set of APIs and noticed a strange "bug".  For most tokens, I can change the last few characters of the token (the "signature") and the request succeeds!

Not every character combination works (token must still be valid base64), but I would expect that signature validation would catch this issue.  Here is my API's token setup

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = EnvironmentVariables.LoadFromAppSettingValue(Configuration["AppSettings:" + EnvironmentVariables. AUTH_URL]),
    Audience = EnvironmentVariables.LoadFromAppSettingValue(Configuration["AppSettings:" + EnvironmentVariables.API_NAME]),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,

    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = EnvironmentVariables.LoadFromAppSettingValue(Configuration["AppSettings:" + EnvironmentVariables. AUTH_URL])
    }
});
```

The "key" parameter above is an `RSASecurityKey`, using the values from the server certificate.

Any ideas as to why the signature validation isn't catching this, or how I might check that signature validation is occurring at all?

My client wants their token system to be bulletproof (who wouldn't) so if this is a normal quirk for JWT I need to know why so that I can remove any concern on their part.

Comment: As base64 strings must all have a length a multiple of 4, and are padded with filler to bring them up to the required length, maybe you're seeing the effect of just changing that 'filler' ... which has no effect on the real message encoded?

Comment: That would be my best guess, and would save me a lot of headache.  Is there a good way to prove that to a client definitively?

Comment: Well if you can change 4 or more of the end characters and it still isn't picked up as an altered signature then something is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started trying to build my own tokens by swapping out valid signatures and body values.  I couldn't, which is great!  At some level signature validation was working.

I decoded two valid base64 signatures (that I had generated for 1 token and were both succeeding authorization), and showed that the produced byte arrays were identical.

That leaves me in a pretty confident state that we do not have a security hole.  Base 64 tokens can be modified, but only if it decodes to the exact same value.  We shouldn't have a risk of someone "building" a token and making up a signature.